# Add a font icon in php

Tags: css, wordpress

Trying to add a fa font icon after the Explore text. Not sure what syntax I need to use.

```
echo '  <a class="quick-view" data-prod="'.$product->get_id().'"href="#quick-view">'.__('Explore','flatsome').'</a>';
```

Comment: which framework you are using for icon?

Comment: Which fa icon and exactly where? Add a placeholder for it so we can help.

Comment: I feel like this isn't really a PHP question

Comment: Use <i class ="fa fa-icon" ></i>

Comment: This looks like a css question though . Remove php tag

Comment: Would like to use the fa-eye icon and display it after the 'Explore' text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put the `<i></i>` after your text

```
echo '<a class="quick-view" data-prod="'.$product->get_id().'"href="#quick-view">'.__('Explore','flatsome').' <i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>';
```

Comment: Thanks just wasn't sure what tag to use!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
echo ' <a class="quick-view fa fa-eye" data-prod="'.$product->get_id().'"href="#quick-view">'.__('Explore','flatsome').'</a>';
```